# Fluid domain does not react to object inside object

Tags: fluid-simulation

My domain doesn't react to text object inside of it (text is inflow and converted to mesh).

I've attached blend file below.
[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh must be closed so that it works as inflow object.

[image]

Your text is open if you look from the other side.